# Magento: Mini Search box not showing after multi domain setup

Tags: magento

I am facing unusual seen in magento, one store was working fine, after that I setup another store in magento and upload another theme in second store. 
After that I noticed that from first store mini search is completly hide or not showing.

Comment: What are you asking.? Not clear. Say more. Visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) site for more information.

Comment: Nicolas visit khappay.pk and olss.pk. you see there is not showing mini search in header of khappay.pk but mini search showing on olss.pk